# $\mathrm{rank}$ inequality about $A,B$ such that $AB=BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Question: Let $A,B\in Mat_n(F)$ such that $AB=BA.$ Show that

1. $r(A)+r(B)\geq r(A+B)+r(AB);$
2. $r(A^2)+r(B^2)\geq 2r(AB).$

---

My work:

1. we show that
   $$\dim\ker A+\dim\ker B\leq \dim\ker (A+B)+\dim\ker AB.$$
   By dimension formula, it's equivalent to
   $$\dim(\ker A+\ker B)+\dim \ker A\cap\ker B\leq\dim\ker(A+B)+\dim\ker AB.$$
2. By 1, we have
   $$\dim\ker(A ^2)+\dim\ker(B^2)\leq \dim\ker(A^2+B^2)+\dim\ker(ABAB).$$
   Since $$\dim\mathrm{Im}\ ABAB=\dim\mathrm{Im}\ AB-\dim \ker AB\cap\mathrm{Im}\ AB,$$
   then  $$\dim\ker ABAB=\dim\ker AB+\dim\ker AB\cap\mathrm{Im}\ AB.$$
   If we show that
   $$\dim\ker (A ^2+B^2)+\dim\ker AB\cap\mathrm{Im}\ AB\leq \dim\ker AB,$$
   it's done. But i have no idea about this.

Comment: You haven't made use of the fact that $AB=BA$.  But if $A$ and $B$ commute, then they preserve each other's (generalized) eigenspaces, if they are diagonalizable then they can be simultaneously diagonalized, and if not they can still be put into compatible block forms.  You may want to explore this angle, or find another way to exploit commutativity (and perhaps look for counterexamples when $A$ and $B$ do not commute).

Comment: @Aaron $\ker A+\ker B\subset\ker AB $ since $AB=BA.$ sorry, i don't write it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\b}[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}$

When $AB=BA$, it is not necessarily that $r(A^2)+r(B^2)\geq 2r(AB).$

Here is a counterexample.

$$A=\b{0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0}$$
$$B=\b{0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0}$$

Then $$A^2=0$$
$$B^2=\b{0&0&0&2\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}$$
$$AB=BA=\b{0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}$$
We have
$$r(A^2)+r(B^2)=0+1=1\lt 2= 2r(AB).$$

Answer (score 1):

The first from the standard observation $\text{Ima}(A+B)\subset\text{Ima}(A)+\text{Ima}(B)$,

noting that $\text{Ima}(A)\cap\text{Ima}(B)\supset\text{Ima}(AB)$.

Where $\text{Ima}(A)$ is the image of the linear map $x\mapsto Ax$, the subspace spanned by the columns of $A$, the set of all vectors that can be written as $Ax$ for some $x$.

Comment: i know how to prove the first. i want the second.